# How to split a string without a delimiter

Tags: python

How can I split the string `'07:05:45PM'` into  `['07:05:45', 'PM']` in Python?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
a = ‘07:05:45PM‘
b = [a[:-2], a[-2:]]
```

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udce2' in position 4: surrogates not allowed

Comment: The time mentioned in OP are all ASCII characters, therefore UTF-8 compatible. What characters are you trying to split?